# Identifying YA Science Fiction Novel

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, audio-book

I'm trying to find a YA novel that I listened to the audiobook version of sometime between 1999 and 2005 (I think).

It was about a segmented future society, where the elite wore blue, the next down wore red & the lowest wore green (I think).

The book was about a pair of elite kids, born to privilege & the social upheaval that comes when they realise their society is built on oppressing the working class.

Other things I remember:

- The kids have a genetically engineered cat as a pet & I'm not talking a tabby, I'm talking about some kind of big cat. Even though there is some major political issues around cloning.
- The kids have a younger sibling who turns out to be a clone, even though that's illegal.
- The lowest status people in this society are farmers, who live outside of the city, in satellite colonies.

Comment: We've had a few stories with color-based societies. I'll see if I can find the matching one.